# How to log in using Active Directory-integrated VMWare SSO

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am integrating using VMWARE SSO which uses JWT token as default to authenticate, but i can't find the jwt in the get call.

Login screen of vmWare:
[login SSO img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hPBS.png)

I already seen the whole documentation about:
https://code.vmware.com/apis/57/idm#/admin

Here is the incoming message from GET:

```
IncomingMessage {
    headers:
     { accept:
        'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'accept-language': 'pt-BR',
       'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
       'user-agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763',
       'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
       host: 'pool.tereos.net',
       connection: 'Keep-Alive',
       cookie:
        '_gid=GA1.2.1964409232.1571847277; _ga=GA1.2.1998153542.1562107100' },
    rawHeaders:
     [ 'Accept',
       'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Language',
       'pt-BR',
       'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',
       '1',
       'User-Agent',
       'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763',
       'Accept-Encoding',
       'gzip, deflate',
       'Host',
       'pool.tereos.net',
       'Connection',
       'Keep-Alive',
       'Cookie',
       '_gid=GA1.2.1964409232.1571847277; _ga=GA1.2.1998153542.1562107100' ]
}
```

The expected result would be the JWT of the authenticated user.

I would like to know how to get this JWT token.

Comment: I don't believe anything in the VMWare Identity Manager API will automagically give you a JWT token. This might help: [Launching Horizon Resources Through Validating Gateways](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Identity-Manager/3.2/com.vmware.wsp-resource/GUID-FD4860FD-EA9C-4A33-A850-058071EC2188.html)